# Can US citizens travel to Australia on a passport with less than 3 months validity?

Tags: passports, us-citizens, australia

Does a US passport holder need 3 extra months of validity on their passport to travel to Australia, or merely a passport that is valid through the duration of their stay? Various third party processors such as iVisa say that the extra 3 months is required, but I cannot find any mention of such a requirement on any Australian government webpage.

Answer (score 7):

You only need your passport to be valid on arrival

From TIMATIC (documents database) :

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid on arrival.

Comment: A quick google does **not** seem to indicate this is the case for Australia, but some visas and ETAs are rejected based on document validity (a subset of the the type of visas/etas that do not transfer across documents) and Timatic does indicate an ETA is required. This answer could be improved with a source (I failed to find one) that would describe the required passport validity to get an Australian ETA.

Answer (score 5):

> Can US citizens travel to Australia on a passport with less than 3 months validity?

Yes. To complement [Nicolas Formichella](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/118049/nicolas-formichella)'s answer, here is a source from an [Australian government webpage](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/crossing-the-border/at-the-border/travel-documents):

> All passengers other than Australian and New Zealand citizens need to present the following documents to officers in immigration clearance:
>
> - a valid passport or other acceptable travel document
> - a [valid visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/) or authority to enter Australia (including electronic visas)
> - a completed and signed [Incoming Passenger card](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/crossing-the-border/at-the-border/incoming-passenger-card-(ipc)), including health and character declaration.
>
> Anyone who arrives without a valid travel document, visa or authority, might be refused entry to Australia or delayed until their identity and claims to enter Australia have been confirmed.

A quick look at [valid visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/)  didn't show any additional requirement on passport validity.

Comment: A quick google does **not** seem to indicate this is the case for Australia, but some visas and ETAs are rejected based on document validity (a subset of the the type of visas/etas that do not transfer across documents), but my point is just that neither your source nor Timatic would mention it if the required ETA would require a longer document validity.

Comment: @DavidMulder You can't get more trustworthy source than the official border agency (which in turn feeds TIMATIC)

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Exactly, which is the needed source to answer the question. If you have a source from the austrialian border agency that states that you don't need additional validity on your passport to get a visa/eta then that's perfect yeah.

Comment: @DavidMulder I stated my source (TIMATIC is a IATA database regarding documentation that is used by nearly all airlines to which government agencies submit their policies) and this answer from Franck does have the appropriate link directly from the aussie gov.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella And the source states that a valid ETA is required, not the requirements for that ETA. During the pandemic for Thailand if I remember correctly you for example needed to get a certain document+QR code from the Thai government, and to get the document you needed to provide proof of health insurance covering COVID19 to the Thai government, but all Timatic showed was that you needed to get this document. Timatic is only about collecting the things the airlines need to check (not something afaik governments submit, but something a trade association collects for its members).

Comment: @DavidMulder perhaps you should post an answer explaining this and suggesting that the traveler apply for the ETA or visa as soon as possible so as to learn whether it will be necessary to replace the passport.

Comment: @DavidMulder A quick look at [valid visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/)  didn't show any additional requirement on passport validity.